# Why weren't many people present at Bruce Wayne's funeral?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-dark-knight-rises

Bruce Wayne is one of the most well known people in Gotham but when he died in *The Dark Knight Rises* only 4 people were present at his funeral.

Only Alfred, Commissioner Gordon, Blake and Lucius. Why did not many people show up to his death?

I mean when he would throw a party almost all the higher class in the city would show up...

As seen in *Batman Begins* a ton of people come just to wish him happy birthday!

Comment: His wishes might have included a private funeral, lots of the 'higher classes' were subject to death by exile, and he famously acted very poorly towards the higher classes in scenes in the 3 movies - like the party where he rudely tells everyone to leave when Ra's Al Ghul  turns up.

Comment: @iandotkelly People did actually come back to his parties after that rude incident (for example, the party that the joker interrupted).

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir ... its one thing to go to a party - you socialize with your friends and acquantances - its another to go to the funeral of someone that was rude to you and reclusive.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, there are a few possible reasons that can be deduced from the movie:

1. **No one knows about his death:** Bruce Wayne has been a recluse for the last 8 years. No one has ever seen him in those 8 years except Alfred and probably Fox (this is shown at the beginning of the movie). So news of his death are only known to those who knew he was Batman (i.e. the four people mentioned in the question). Not one of them has a reason to broadcast that, especially at this time when Gotham is in chaos after Bane's deeds.
2. **People are too busy dealing with their own problems to show up:** Bane ravaged Gotham and left it in chaos. And a lot of rich Gothamites (who constitute the majority, if not all, of Wayne's friends) were executed by Crane (Scarecrow). So the rest of them, who survived, would have much important things to do than showing up for Wayne's funeral, a man they haven't seen in 8 years.
3. **That is not Bruce Wayne's funeral:** Alfred might have already organized a funeral for Wayne that a lot of people showed up for. The four might have gathered there to mourn Batman as two of them (Blake and Gordon) didn't know Bruce Wayne that well, so they're not considered friends of Wayne per se.

Comment: I'll go for the first one. Who cares about a death of ghost